# how to get the distance of sequence of nodes in pgr_dijkstra pgrouting?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mysql-python, pgrouting

I have an array of integers(nodes or destinations) i.e array[2,3,4,5,6,8] that need to be visited in the given sequence.
What I want is, to get the shortest distance using pgr_dijkstra. But the pgr_dijkstra finds the shortest path for two points, therefore I need to find the distance of each pair using pgr_dijkstra and adding all distances to get the total distance.
The pairs will be like
2,3
3,4

4,5

5,6

6,8.
Is there any way to define a function that takes this array and finds the shortest path using pgr_dijkstra.

Query is:
**for 1st pair(2,3)**
`SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid as id,source, target, rcost_len AS cost FROM finalroads',2,3, false);`

**for 2nd pair(3,4)**
`SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid as id,source, target, rcost_len AS cost FROM finalroads'***,3,4,*** false)`

**for 3rd pair(4,5)**
`SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid as id,source, target, rcost_len AS cost FROM finalroads'***,4,5,*** false)`;

**NOTE:** The array size is not fixed, it can be different.

Is there any way to automate this in postgres sql may be using a loop etc?
Please let me know how to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution provided in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/getting-multiple-shortest-paths-with-pgrouting-in-one-query) that makes use of a source **table**, it is possible to use your array. Note that the `orig` is your array omitting the last entry, and the `dest` omits the 1st entry.

```sql
SELECT 
  source, 
  target,
  (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM  -- or whatever you want to do with the routing result
     (SELECT * 
      FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid as id,source, target, rcost_len AS cost FROM finalroads',
                        orig,
                        dest, 
                        false))
     ) AS foo 
  ) AS cost
FROM (
  select unnest(myarray[:array_upper(myarray,1)-1])  as orig,
         unnest(myarray[2:]) as dest 
  from (select array[1,2,3,4] myarray) b) c;
```

Comment: I implemented this in python 
    `  seq=[1,2,3,4,5]
            sum_=0.00
            for j in range(0,len(seq)-1):
                c=seq[j]
                d=seq[j+1]
                cur.execute("""SELECT sum(cost) as Cos FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid as id,source, target, len_km AS cost FROM finalroads',%s, %s, false, false)""",(c,d))
                mcc=cur.fetchall()
              
                sum_=sum_+mcc[0][0]
            Dis.append(sum_) b`  but this one and the one implemented in python takes the same time. Is there any way to get the results faster?

Comment: @Ayaz49 it is expected to take about the same time, the same function being called the same number of times in both cases. You should work on making `pg_dijkstra()` faster, but that should be a different question.

Comment: thank you so much for ur help sir, I will look into it,

Answer (score 0):

If you want all pairs distance then use

select * from pgr_apspJohnson ('SELECT gid as id,source, target, rcost_len AS cost FROM finalroads)